# Is there a way to show local notification when application is in foreground

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I am aware of a standard way of handling local notification when app is in foreground:

- receive application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
- show an UIAlertView in it (or any other UI)

My question is whether it's possible at all (even using private api) to show notification message in the statusbar area when application is in foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my knowledge NO.

#### My suggestion

The best option will be, you need to add a banner on top of your application to show the effect of UILocalNotification. It'll be better than relying on private API's (if any).

Comment: Or perhaps offer a different experience entirely when your app is in the foreground and you want to show a notification.... since your user is already in your app.